# Google+ Sharing Site Via Link - Not Parsing Rich Preview

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

I'm at a loss and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

For whatever reason when sharing posts from www.southpugetsoundnews.com with Google+ it just returns the HTML Link. No Preview, No Thumb. However I can access it via http://www.google.com/gwt/x?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.southpugetsoundnews.com without incident and using the Rich Preview Snippet tool as well.

Is there a known issue with WordPress Jetpack and it's Google Sharing? I know it's not the server, since I have more accounts on the same box and google snips those fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

A rich preview for www.southpugetsoundnews.com is unavailable because the site is currently returning a 406 Not Acceptable in response to an HTTP GET.

```
 HTTP/1.0 406 Not Acceptable
 Date: Tue, 10 Jul 2012 23:57:14 GMT
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
 Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
 Cache-Control: max-age=3, must-revalidate
 WP-Super-Cache: Served supercache file from PHP
```